# Replace semicolon in quotes (Nintex Workflow)

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I need to parse CSV file which is semicolon delimited in Nintex workflows. The lines will be splitted by ; which is not an issue.

However, there are escaped semicolons - that means they are wrapped in quotes example:

```
column1;column2;"column3; stillcolumn 3";column4
```

I have a regex which can find a match - but it will find only 1 match. How to force Nintex to get/replace all occurrences?

Regex:

```
("[^";]*);([^"]*";)
```

In .NET it is Regex.Matches, in JS there is an option /g but I do not know about any option in Nintex (except running this regex in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

you can either use the RegEx action which should do what you ask provided it is setup right. Also if the data is in a string you could use the build string action, together with an inline function to replace certain characters with another.

Can you please post this to the http://community.nintex.com site and tag me. I cam then take a deeper look into it and try and reproduce

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to split the string by ; , your RegEx just would be:

```
;
```

By this way, you'll obtain:

```
[column1, column2, "column3, stillcolumn 3", column4]
```